# What would be the best approach for fixing compromised framing members?

Tags: repair, framing, studs

I recently opened an exterior wall to add insulation. Along the kitchen wall where plumbing was added as part of a kitchen remodel the predated our buying the house, I discovered several of the framing studs, all load-bearing, had been drastically cut to make room for the new plumbing. I can't imagine the studs still meet code and I'd like to address the issue while I have the wall open. What would be the best way to reinforce the studs without removing the pipes? Has anyone had to deal with something similar?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**

These are some of the repairs I made. I didn't find any hardware available locally and so relied on sister studs and replacing portions of compromised studs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get freezing temperatures?  From adding more insulation where the pipes are, I imagine you do.  It is a PITA but the best choice is to bring those pipes inside of the wall and add good 2x4s to those busted ones.  Being an outside wall it does have load bearing use and what is left of those studs are not doing their job.

Comment: @Ruskes  OP and the last picture say it is an outside/exterior wall.  OP is there, we are not.  In two pictures the studs look/seem like they are buckling

Comment: @Ruskes: The opening sentence of the question reads, "I recently opened an **exterior** wall to add insulation". "Exterior wall" is a big phrase word meaning "outside wall". Before making useless comments, _please_ carefully read the question...

Comment: Something like this may suit you: https://www.macombgroup.com/2337059/product/macomb-group-approved-533-3  Can't say anything about pipes running through an exterior wall though.  At least they appear to be drains, and not supplies.

Comment: 3rd pic down shows 2 pipes running through a stud. One appears to be smaller and slightly tan in color, which makes me believe that it's a CPVC supply line (I've got some of those in my house).  TBH, I think that these studs need to be replaced to remedy the compromise in the wall structure. As huge as those holes are, I'm not sure anyone makes a stud shoe that would repair these...

Comment: 2nd pic also looks like a CPVC supply line _and_ it looks like someone may have tried to support this by nailing on some OSB to the side of the stud away from the camera. Can you add a pic of the other side of that stud?

Comment: Are these studs 1.5" wide (current 2x4 standard) or an actual 2" wide?

Comment: How about a photo of the whole mess of plumbing? And what are the pipe sizes? Even a 1.5" pipe exceeds the code's 40% stud width maximum size for drilled holes, where even 1.5" pipe without stud shoes and done right in that 3.5" wall cavity would require doubled up studs which aren't allowed more than twice in a row (and they displace a ton of insulation). Most likely doing it right would entail replacing most of the studs with tighter notched studs and installing stud shoes around most of _those_ notches. Maybe you can find giant stud shoes for retrofitting the existing framing, though.

Comment: Update. So your wall studs work in bending to transfer wind loads to floor elevations where these loads then find their way to the foundation. Fortunately your notches are low where the bending stresses are relatively small. I would bet that these stresses are about 25% of the maximum from the middle of each stud. Your new weakly oriented blocks have about 50% of the bending strength of the strongly oriented studs, so these blocks are probably adequate if you fastened them sufficiently to develop 50% of their bending strength (50%*50% = 25%).

Comment: Update. Your wall studs also work in compression to transfer gravity and live loads to the foundation. Slender members like wall studs fail in buckling long before the wood material crushes. Is your fix better than it was before? Certainly. Is it adequate to withstand your home's full design live load? I'm skeptical. The problem is that buckling strength depends on a column's bending stiffness, where I suspect that your wall studs have severely reduced bending stiffness (compared to an un-notched wall stud, not that mess that you had before). The...

Comment: ...location away from the middle again works in your favor, but in this case the problem spreads to impact the whole member's effectiveness. The good news is that the design live load in a residential home's communal areas is the same as it is in a parking structure, so you're probably safe as long as you don't park a Buick in your living room. Single story home in an area with substantial snow? Then you might be in trouble when the next 50 year snowfall comes along. (Having a long row of beaten up studs like that would bug me, but I don't have an easy solution.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of narrow spaces that will not allow new material added as a "flat stud to sister along side the existing. That would be my first option. The firring out of the wall as mentioned in the comments by matt. is a good option too, since the pipes will get more insulation around them to prevent freezing.

If neither of those are viable options, you may want to get a few metal gussets fabricated, perhaps if you are handy you can cut them yourself, by getting some 2"X1/4" thick bar stock about 6 ft long for each location, or perhaps one for each side, and notch to go around the pipes centered on the length where possible and drill the rest of it to take a LOT of structural screws, say about a dozen or more on each side of the pipe and a few along the narrow spot, to help prevent buckling.

Perhaps a few of the pipes can be temporarily removed, the plate drilled and the pipes reinstalled. If so a wider plate can be used to allow a clean hole with metal all around. If you do that, 4 ft pieces may do, instead of 6 ft.

Comment: thanks. Any recommendations for the studs that looks like they might be buckling a bit already? Just try to stop if from buckling anymore?

Comment: You could try to lift the wall up a bit, but it would need to be lifted at multiple points from the outside, with a temp. continuous sill on flattened dirt and "jack posts" driven in to take up the load over the length of the wall or the area in question. My suggestion would be 3 per stud repair, one at the stud, and one on the adjacent studs.  This is to keep a heavy point load on just one jack post. Doing this, in any fashion may crack the wall material on the inside, so it may be best left as is. The wall settled over time and will not like going back in place all at once.

Comment: The steel plate with all the  structural "shear screws" will keep it from buckling/dropping anymore.

Comment: Instead of making it up on the go and attempting more at-home-hackery, use a "stud shoe" that's specifically designed to repair a stud. They've actually been designed and tested and determined to be suitable for purpose as opposed to more "by guess and by gosh" which may end up with a collapsed house.

Comment: @FreeMan Your answer or the lack off,  could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center

Comment: Not sure what you're on about, @Ruskes... I see your now deleted answer, and you changed the pics to actually show stud shoes, and I think that's a much better answer now than it was. I would have retracted my vote, but can't. TBH, not sure there's much that can be done for the OP's studs without some rebuilding...

Comment: @FreeMan stud shoes don't fit on studs that predate the current dimensional standards for 2x lumber

Answer (score 1):

The International Residential Code (IRC) prescribes permissible notches, where there's one standard for exterior and/or load bearing walls and there's another standard for interior, non-load bearing walls. From the 2018 IRC:

[image: 2018 IRC Excerpt]

For your exterior wall, IRC 602.6(1) prescribes a maximum notch depth of 25%. The builders have clearly violated this standard. Notice that the IRC carves out an exception for "use of approved stud shoes...where they are installed in accordance with the manufacturer's recommendations." Before mail ordering stud shoes for repairing your damage, then, be sure to read these "manufacturer's recommendations" first to verify that they're a suitable for your use case.

For some of your nastier cuts, I know that Simpson makes a 3" wide shoe presumably for doubled up wall studs. I assume that you would sister up a new stud beside the mutilated ones and in between pipe interruptions so that the 3" shoe can wrap your new stud and the old one. Unfortunately that "manufacturer's recommendations" indicates that you can't just assume that they're up to whatever detailing that you throw at them. Well, if you're doing this without a building official breathing down your neck, then you can do whatever you want, but I wouldn't want to invest all of that effort into code non-conformant work.

Your case is clear cut in need of stud shoes, but sometimes you can repair such damage by installing replacement studs oriented 90 degrees from the familiar orientation. For interior, non-load bearing walls, you can install 2X4s on 16 inch centers at this skinny orientation that allows 2" of clearance before notching.